# How to get the dataframe with all rows after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe:

df

```
    Date   Close    Open 
0 2012-01-02  348.36  342.19 
1 2012-01-03  355.23  350.24 
2 2012-01-04  354.00  352.84 
3 2012-01-05  352.23  352.12 
4 2012-01-06  351.24  351.97
```

The `df` has a 14000 rows.

I want to `groupby` year and month and get a `multiindex` dataframe.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 
# df.set_index('Date',inplace=True,drop=True)
df1 = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year.rename('year'),df.Date.dt.month.rename('month')]).values
```

I have tried `.values` `.count`(doesn't give my expected output).

expected output:

```
 df1

year   month Date        Close    Open 
2012   1     2012-01-02  348.36  342.19 
             2012-01-03  355.23  350.24 
             2012-01-04  354.00  352.84 
             2012-01-05  352.23  352.12 
             2012-01-06  351.24  351.97
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 

df1 = df.set_index([df.Date.dt.year.rename('year'),df.Date.dt.month.rename('month')])
```

Similar with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index([df.Date.dt.year,df.Date.dt.month]).rename_axis(['year','month'])
```

---

```
print (df1)
                 Date   Close    Open
year month                           
2012 1     2012-01-02  348.36  342.19
     1     2012-01-03  355.23  350.24
     1     2012-01-04  354.00  352.84
     1     2012-01-05  352.23  352.12
     1     2012-01-06  351.24  351.97
```

Another solutions (more verbose):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.Date.dt.year.rename('year'),
                                      df.Date.dt.month.rename('month')])
```

---

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.Date.dt.year,
                                      df.Date.dt.month], names=('year','month'))
```